# Linq - multiple rows as string

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq

Lets assume that I have Table which contains Username and the other one which contains FirstName. A single user can have multiple FirstNames:

How can I obtain a record which will contain Username and all first names separated by comma?

i. e.

```
Users
id | Username
1 | Test

Names
UserId | FirstName
1 | Mike
1 | John
```

I would like to receive a record which will contain

Test, "Mike, John"

How can I do that?

**Edit**: What if Users table will have more columns which I want to get?

i. e.

```
id | Username | Status
1  | Test     | Active
```

How to get `Test, Active, "Mike, John"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` and `String.Join`

```
var userGroups = from u in users
     join n in names
     on u.ID equals n.UserID
     group new{n, u} by n.UserID into UserGrp
     select new
     {
         Username = UserGrp.Key,
         Status = UserGrp.First().u.Status,
         Names = string.Join(",", UserGrp.Select(x => x.n.Name))
     };

foreach (var ug in userGroups)
   Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, \"{2}\"", ug.Username, ug.Status, ug.Names);
```

Comment: @szaman: Corrected  little bug(s): now grouping by `UserID` and changed: `UNameGrp.First(x => x.u.Status)` to => `UNameGrp.First().u.Status`.