# Linq query to merge distinct items in a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following model:

```
public class Result
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }        
}
```

And I have a List with data similar to the following:

```
Id        Company
=================
21        Microsoft
22        Apple
22        IBM
23        Microsoft
```

How can I use Linq to give me the distinct ID's, concatenating the Company column with a delimiter?

My output should be:

```
Id        Company
=================
21        Microsoft
22        Apple, IBM
23        Microsoft
```

Comment: Unrelated - Still, Why is IBM alone in black ?

Comment: @Kiran that block is formatted as code.  Because this post has a c# tag,  It has been interpreted as c# code.  The markup parser determined that it needs to be a different font color.

Comment: @Kiran Google Code Prettify for C# enforces the suggestion that types have to have a Uppercase character first followed by a lowercase character, so it doesn't recognise it as a type (class name) like the rest of the words in the tables.

Comment: In case anybody is wondering why this question has 15 downvotes: [it was linked](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291081/does-a-well-explained-question-nullify-a-no-research-effort-downvote) from meta.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/15753015, http://stackoverflow.com/q/12563328, http://stackoverflow.com/q/12322330, and http://stackoverflow.com/q/22943022

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` and `String.Join`:

```
IEnumerable<Result> query = results.GroupBy(r => r.Id)
    .Select(g => new Result
    { 
        Id = g.Key, 
        Company = String.Join(", ", g.Select(r => r.Company)) 
    });
```

Comment: You need to add Distinct after the Select(r=>r.Company) otherwise you may get duplicates (assume you don't want duplicates).

Comment: @Peter: i only know that OP wants unique ID's, he hasn't mentioned that the company must also be distinct.

Comment: Correct, Company is not unique

Answer (score 8):

A slightly different take on Tim's excellent answer if there are duplicate records in your source and you don't want Company names repeated in the same Field:

```
var data = new List<Result>
{
    new Result {Id = 21, Company = "Microsoft"},
    new Result {Id = 22, Company = "Apple"},
    new Result {Id = 22, Company = "IBM"},
    new Result {Id = 23, Company = "Microsoft"},
    new Result {Id = 23, Company = "Microsoft"}
};

var x = data.GroupBy(d => d.Id)
             .Select(d => new Result { Id = d.Key, 
                                       Company = 
                               string.Join(",", d.Select(s => s.Company).Distinct())});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var groupesList = result.GroupBy(x => x.Id,
     (key, val) => new { Key = key, Value = string.Join(",", val.Select(r => r.Company)} ).ToList();
```

then you can call Key(unuque) or Value by key for all inform for example all ID

Answer (score 4):

Simply use [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.groupby(v=vs.100).aspx) and [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods:-

```
List<Result> result = Results.GroupBy(x => x.id)
                    .Select(x => new Result
                         { 
                            Id = x.Key, 
                            Company = String.Join(",",x.Select(z => z.Company) 
                         }).ToList();
```

Comment: that's just a copy of tim's answer!

Comment: 60 seconds difference is huge!!!